# Using ContextApi in SvelteKit in +page.server.ts

Tags: javascript, web, sveltekit

I have a `SvelteKit` application connected to external API. After user opens my website I fetch user data from external API and save it in store wrapped in `ContextAPI` (based on https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/state-management#using-stores-with-context) but
when i try to use `getContext('user')` in +page.server.ts I'm getting an error:

`Error: Function called outside component initialization`

My question is: How can I get access to this data on load function in `+page.server.ts` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stores and contexts are for pages and components, you should or cannot use them on the server.

What you can do, is get data from a `+layout.server.ts` file, via the event object's `parent`.

```js
export const load: PageServerLoad = async e =>
{
    const layoutData = await e.parent();
    ...
```

Note that this is generally not necessary. The page will get merged layout and page data automatically, so this really is only useful if the `load` function itself needs access.

Comment: Sorry to necro, but does it means you can access the context in a `+page.ts` as this file "can" be run by the client ?

Comment: @Skylli: Contexts are a component concept, they are inherited within the component hierarchy. So you can e.g. set contexts in a `+layout.svelte` and it will be available in  the `+page.svelte` component and its descendants. You may or may not be able to use them in certain functions, but this is as far as I know undefined behavior. Would stick to only using them in components (i.e. `.svelte` files) and code that you know is executed from valid component code (since context also cannot be used everywhere in a component).